# Custom query to fetch all entries of a table and that only contains first of many duplicates based on a specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Location model and the table looks like

| id | name | vin | ip_address | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | default | 0 | 0.0.0.0/0 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623 |
| 1 | admin | 1 | 10.108.150.143 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 2 | V122 | 122 | 10.108.150.122 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 3 | V123 | 123 | 10.108.150.123 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 4 | V124 | 124 | 10.108.150.124 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 5 | V122 | 122 | 10.108.150.122 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 6 | V125 | 122 | 10.108.150.125 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |

My method in the Location model

```ruby
   def self.find_all_non_duplicate
     return self.find(:all, :conditions => "id <> 1")
   end
```

I want to fetch all entries of the locations table except the entry with id = 1 and that contains only the first entry of many duplicates based on the column **ip_address**.

Since ip_address of **id = 2 and id = 5** is duplicate. I want to keep the **first entry of many** duplicates i.e., **id = 2**.

The  expected result is

| id | name | vin | ip_address | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | default | 0 | 0.0.0.0/0 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623 |
| 2 | V122 | 122 | 10.108.150.122 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 3 | V123 | 123 | 10.108.150.123 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 4 | V124 | 124 | 10.108.150.124 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |
| 6 | V125 | 122 | 10.108.150.125 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885 |

**The entries with id's 1 and 5 to be ignored**

Comment: is using something like `self.where.not(id: 1)` doesn’t work? Further if you want to exclude id=5 `self.where.not(id: [1,5])`

Comment: I guess this should do the trick `where.not(id: 1).group(:name)`

Comment: @Chris, thank you for the suggestion. I elaborated my question for more clarity.

Comment: ok here is the updated version `where.not(id: 1).where("id in (select min(id) from #{self.table_name} group by ip_address)")`

Comment: @Chris While this works, it ends up being a longer and slower imitation of `distinct on`, a standard PostgreSQL clause designed and optimised for this purpose. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-select.html#:%7E:text=is%20the%20default.-,SELECT%20DISTINCT%20ON,-(%20expression%20%5B%2C%20...%5D%20)%20keeps%20only) proposed to RoR quite recently [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/99c1741dc4fd25dcb195d3297597f8ab0fc5a18e) but [not yet merged](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41622), as pointed out by [@engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky). In a raw SQL form it would look like this:

```sql
select distinct on (ip_address) * 
from test 
where id<>1 
order by ip_address,created_at;
```

Which would translate to RoR's

```ruby
self.where("id <> 1").distinct_on(:ip_address)
```

or, until the new feature gets accepted:

```ruby
self.where("id <> 1").select("distinct on (ip_address) *")
```

Full db-side test:

```sql
drop table if exists test cascade;
create table test (
    id serial primary key,
    name text,
    vin integer,
    ip_address inet,
    created_at timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp);
insert into test 
(id,name,vin,ip_address,created_at,updated_at)
values
(0,'default', 0,'0.0.0.0/0'::inet,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623'::timestamp,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623'::timestamp),
(1,'admin',   1,'10.108.150.143'::inet,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp),
(2,'V122',    122,'10.108.150.122'::inet,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp),
(3,'V123',    123,'10.108.150.123'::inet,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp),
(4,'V124',    124,'10.108.150.124'::inet,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp),
(5,'V122',    122,'10.108.150.122'::inet,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp),
(6,'V125',    122,'10.108.150.125'::inet,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp,'2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885'::timestamp);

select distinct on (ip_address) * 
from test where id<>1 
order by ip_address,created_at;
-- id |  name   | vin |   ip_address   |         created_at         |         updated_at
------+---------+-----+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
--  0 | default |   0 | 0.0.0.0/0      | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.822623
--  2 | V122    | 122 | 10.108.150.122 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885  | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885
--  3 | V123    | 123 | 10.108.150.123 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885  | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885
--  4 | V124    | 124 | 10.108.150.124 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885  | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885
--  6 | V125    | 122 | 10.108.150.125 | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885  | 2021-11-08 11:54:26.82885
--(5 rows)
```

Comment: The combination of `distinct_on` and that finder are naturally impossible. The specified finder condition was removed in rails 4 and the `distinct_on` method does not appear to have been accepted by rails for any release at the moment [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/41622)

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks. I've corrected the answer to use a simple `.where` and `.select` - I initially wanted to suggest just the addition of either `distinct_on` or an equivalent `select` to what the author's already using, but I ended up not verifying if the combination works. I also underlined that the change still hasn't been accepted - previously I did sound like the change was already merged.